# How do I get the current position of the caret in a text-field in JavaScript/Vue?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm attempting to implement a small quality of life change to a text field to allow users to change the dollar amount of a text field if the cents are full.

Currently, my fields will append a decimal amount based on what has been entered when the user moves onto another field (triggering an `@blur` event).

- `1` will become `1.00`
- `1.` will become `1.00`
- `1.5` will become `1.50`

The way I have it coded is to check if the field matches a regex  (`/((\d*\.){1}(\d{2}))/`) to see if the field is "full". If so, I want to get the user's caret/cursor/insertion point/whatever term it is to check and see if it's before or after the decimal point.

- If it's before the decimal point, i.e. `100|.00`, I want them to be able to enter more numbers.
- If it's after the decimal point, i.e. `100.|00`, I **don't** want them to be able to enter more numbers.

This sounds like a job for `refs` and `selectionStart/selectionEnd`, and you'd *almost* be right (and you probably still are). Even after Google removed that functionality for fields with `type="number"`, there was a work around using those properties. I've seen many different posts suggesting that, some dating back almost 13 years. I just can't seem to get it to work right though.

Here's what I have:

---

### Template tag

```
<v-container>
    <v-row v-for="(exp, index) in travelExpenseArray" :key="exp.id" style="margin-top: -20px;" >
        <v-col v-show="$vuetify.breakpoint.smAndUp" cols="auto" sm="2" />
        <v-col cols="auto" sm="4" >
            <v-checkbox  v-model="exp.checked" :label="exp.title" dense @change="checkEnabled(index, exp.checked)"/>
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="auto" sm="4">
            <v-card-text style="padding: 0px;">{{exp.title}} Expenses</v-card-text>
            <v-text-field :ref="`vtf${index}`" outlined step=".01" v-model="exp.expense" type="number" hide-details
            dense single-line :disabled="!exp.checked" hide-spin-buttons @keypress="checkValidKey($event, index)" 
            @click="clearCurrencyField(index)" @blur="appendZeros(index)"/>
        </v-col>
        <v-col v-show="$vuetify.breakpoint.smAndUp" cols="auto" sm="2" />
    </v-row>

    <v-row style="margin-top: -20px;">
        <v-col cols="auto" sm="6" />
        <v-col cols="auto" sm="4">
            <v-card-text style="padding: 0px">Total Travel Expenses</v-card-text>
            <v-text-field outlined v-model="totalTravelExpenses" dense disabled />
        </v-col>
        <v-col v-show="$vuetify.breakpoint.smAndUp" cols="auto" sm="2" />
    </v-row>
</v-container>
```

To break it down: I have a travel expense array that I loop over and dynamically create text fields for, `v-model`-ing the values from the array to the ones from the text fields. I'm fortunately able to create dynamic `ref=''` attributes, which will come in handy in the script section.

---

### Script Tag

(specifically, the checkValidKey method, where this is happening)

```
checkValidKey(evt, index){
    let expense = this.travelExpenseArray[index].expense;               
    // Get the key code from the event.
    const charCode = evt.which ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;

    // Ensure key is a valid key ('0-9.' and numpad '0-9.').
    // Prevent if there's no match.
    if(!this.getValidKeys().includes(charCode)){
        evt.preventDefault();

    // okay so this block checks the expense against the regex
    // if it matches, (tentatively) prevent the key press 
    // because a 'full' cost has been entered.
    }else if((/((\d*\.){1}(\d{2}))/).test(expense)){

        // chrome removed this functionality for `type = "number"` fields in 2014 or so
        this.$refs[`vtf${index}`][0].$refs.input.type = "text";
        console.log(this.$refs[`vtf${index}`][0].$refs.input.selectionStart);
        // not typing all that out over and over
        let selection = {
            start: this.$refs[`vtf${index}`][0].$refs.input.selectionStart,
            end: this.$refs[`vtf${index}`][0].$refs.input.selectionEnd
        }
                    
        // check if the cursor is in a valid position
        if(selection.start >= selection.end - 2){
            evt.preventDefault();
        }
        // should probably do this to be safe; this seems like
        // a really hacky solution to such a negligible problem
        this.$refs[`vtf${index}`][0].$refs.input.type = "number";
                    
        return;
    }
},
```

The comments say the same thing but first I get the value of the key pressed. If it's not in a list of valid keys, ignore the press. If it is, and the value of the field matches the regex, I get the field by it's `$ref` with a little bit of black magic that I feel shouldn't work, but consider myself fortunate that it does. I convert the type to text to allow me to use `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd`, and I then take what are supposed to be the start and end points and store them in an object to do a little bit of shorthand. I do a comparison, and if it passes, I prevent the key from registering. Then I convert the type of field back to number and return.

Also, here's how the expenses are structured in the vuex store, in case that's useful:

```
travelExpenseArray: [
    {id: 0, title: 'Bus', checked: false, expense: '0.00'},
    {id: 1, title: 'Car', checked: false, expense: '0.00'},
    {id: 2, title: 'Plane', checked: false, expense: '0.00'},
    {id: 3, title: 'Train', checked: false, expense: '0.00'},
],
```

The issue I'm running into is that for some reason, `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` are both coming up as `0`. I understand that this is likely because no text is *actually selected*, but there's no `getCaretPosition`method or `caretPosition` property. I would really love for this workaround to... work, but I also don't want to keep wasting time hoping it does when it won't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I was doing was easily accomplished (and more) by just installing a library instead of reinventing the wheel.

I just installed `v-money` with `npm install v-money`.

### App.vue

---

Added the following lines:

```
import money from 'v-money';
Vue.use(money);
```

### TravelExpenseForm.vue

(the component that uses this method)

---

Modified the `v-text-field` to include the `v-money="money"` directive.

Added the following object to the data option:

```
money: {
    decimal: '.',
    thousands: ',',
    prefix: '$',
    suffix: '',
    precision: 2
}
```